# Space between elements using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

EDIT:

I have updated my demo on JsFiddle please have a look at it.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/sfuanbLL/2/)

I'm not sure what is it that causing the space between inputs and you can see its very inconsistency and give space, what is it that is missing?

<s>[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/abuhamzah/pen/VvRMrJ)</s>

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-12">    
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active cont" id="we">
            <span style="float: right; padding: 4px 6px;"><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Go Back to Previous Page</a> </span>
            <span style="float: right; padding: 4px 6px;"><font color="red">*</font> Indicates required field</span>
            <div class="cl-mcont">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="block-flat">
                            <div class="page-head">
                                <h3>
                                        Bootstrap Template
                                    </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <form action="/xcel" class="form-horizontal data-parsley-validate" id="fForm" method="post">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                                Category</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <select class="select2" id="on" style="width:250px;">
                                                    <option value="Production">Production</option>
                                                    <option value="Production">Production</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                                Tier</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <select class="select2" id="tw" style="width:250px;">
                                                    <option value="Production">Production</option>
                                                    <option value="Production">Production</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                                Name</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <input class="form-control" id="te" placeholder="  Name" type="text" value="" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                                Code</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <input class="form-control" id="df" name="ClientCode" placeholder="  Code" type="text" value="" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                                Model</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <input class="form-control" id="adg" placeholder="  Model" type="text" value="" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                                Center</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <input class="form-control" id="fd" placeholder="  Center" type="text" value="" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                                Center</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <input class="form-control" id="sa" placeholder="  Center" type="text" value="" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                                Name</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <input class="form-control" id="aeh" placeholder="  Name" type="text" value="" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                                CI </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <input class="form-control" id="he" placeholder="CI  " type="text" value="" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                                Production </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <input class="form-control" id="jg" placeholder="Production   IP" type="text" value="" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                                Action</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <select class="select2" id="lk" style="width:250px;">
                                                    <option value="Production">Production</option>
                                                    <option value="Production">Production</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                                Description</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <input class="form-control" id="ui" placeholder="  Description" type="text" value="" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style='clear: both'>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style='clear: both'>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                                Physical </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <select class="select2" id="lj" style="width:250px;">
                                                    <option value="Production">Production</option>
                                                    <option value="Production">Production</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                                Read</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <input class="form-control" id="io" placeholder="  Read" type="text" value="" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                                Write</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <input class="form-control" id="po" placeholder="  Write" type="text" value="" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                                Test</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <select class="select2" id=".j" style="width:265px;">
                                                    <option value="Production">Production</option>
                                                    <option value="Production">Production</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group"> </div>

                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `.col-md-6` elements of unequal height.
The next (third) `.col-md-6` will always go on the next row, starting from under the tallest of the previous siblings.
If you want to remove that space, you need to make the first `.col-md-6` equal in height with the second one, by adding more padding around its inner elements (the `.select2`s).

UPDATE. One more thing I am noticing: in order to benefit the most from bootstrap's CSS you should stick to its' markup. You are supposed to place `.col-XX-Y` as direct children of `.row` or `.row-fluid` elements. Otherwise you will ask yourself why certain elements seem miss-aligned and it they will be a pain to fix at different responsive levels.

---

As per comments, I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sfuanbLL/5/).

In order to make the two columns equal I made the `select2`s equal in height as the bootstrap inputs:

```
.select2-container .select2-selection--single { 
    height: 34px; 
}
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
    line-height: 34px;
}

.select2-container {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Please take note I also removed some inline styling from your html, it's not only the CSS.

Comment: Yep. The first two chidren of `form#fForm` are unequal. First has 84px height and second is 118px. At least in your codepen.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask you again but how did you figured 84px height and 118px ? I am still-unable to find the diff? Maybe I need glasses

Comment: Firstly, this difference is in your codepen demo, which clearly is missing some css, comparing it to the picture you posted. Secondly, if you use Chrome, hovering an element in the Elements panel in Developer Tools panel it will show the calculated width and height of that element. That's what I use, but I hear FF dev tools have similar functionality. Whatever rocks your boat. But you need inspecting tools for debugging CSS, that's for sure.

Comment: I know about the browser tools but I thought you see that in the HTML  never mind, I will look into it thanks.

Comment: I have updated my question and have fixed the css on `select2` have a look at it please, still could not able to figured out https://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/sfuanbLL/2/

Comment: I have updated your fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/sfuanbLL/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/sfuanbLL/3/). Please notice I also removed some inline styling to make it look right. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: 1+ Thanks for your help :)